# Headers in $resources not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send a header which each HTTP for a ngResource (auth token in this case)

This somewhats works :

```
app.factory('User', ['$resource','$window',
  function($resource,$window,liftHost, liftBasePath) {

     return $resource('/api/users/:id',{},{ 
      get: {
               method: 'GET',
               headers: {'token': $window.sessionStorage.token}
          }

     });
  }]);
```

The problem with this code, is that after the first call, each GET request will have the same header value.  It does not get re-evaluated. So if a users logs out, and then log backs in, this will change the value of *$window.sessionStorage.token*, but the request will be sent using the previous value of the token.

I have created a small plunker with $httpBackend mocks to illustrate it.

see : http://plnkr.co/edit/xYZM6wlDJ6CH2BPHLZAC?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w10g5y?p=preview) with this working

I introduced a TokenService that is injected into the User and Session services. This is a bit cleaner than depending on the $window service. Also, I made the token an object rather than a primitive string. This allows the token to be passed around by reference rather than value.

```
app.factory('Token', [
  function() {
    return {
      value: "a"
    }
  }
]);
```